# Call function every x time without blocking the GUI Java

Tags: java, multithreading, observable

I have a class caled ItemGUI which is handling everything related with the user interface. The user, is able to add some links, which are the items, so when he inserts a link and clicks on the ADD button, it should create a new object of the class Item and start running a function called getPrice(), something like that:

```
Item newItem = new Item(newItemField.getText());
// should also be added to a list of items which should be in the ItemGUI class
newItem.getPrice()
```

This should be done after clicking the add button. Then I print the item to the table. The problem is that the method getPrice() should run every 5 seconds without blocking my GUI, so I should implement Threads.

My question is: how can I be able to implement a thread that runs that function (for each item in the list) every 5 seconds until I click on a stop button? I was thinking about using the observer-observable classes with a clock that notifies its observers every 5 seconds. Will this be the best option?
Also, will I be able to retrieve the item variables from the ItemGUI class?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using Swing, you should use either a SwingWorker or a Swing Timer

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

The clearest solution by MadProgrammer's suggestion is to use [swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), like this:

```
protected javax.swing.Timer refresherTimer = null;
protected void stopRefreshing() {
    if (refresherTimer != null) {
        refresherTimer.stop();
        refresherTimer = null;
    }
}
protected void startRefreshing() {
    stopRefreshing();
    refresherTimer = new Timer(500, e -> {
        newItem.getPrice()
    });
    refresherTimer.start();
}
public void onStartButtonClicked() {
    Item newItem = new Item(newItemField.getText());
    // here newItem should be added to a list of items which should be in the ItemGUI class
    startRefreshing();
}
public void onStopButtonClicked() {
    stopRefreshing();
}
```

**Original answer**

It would be nice to have some utility named e.g. `GuiTimer` which would make your task as easy as:

```
protected GuiThread.Task refresherTask = null;
protected void cancelRefreshing() {
    if (refresherTask != null) {
        refresherTask.cancel();
        refresherTask = null;
    }
}
public void onStartButtonClicked() {
    Item newItem = new Item(newItemField.getText());
    // should also be added to a list of items which should be in the ItemGUI class
    cancelRefreshing();
    refresherTask = GuiThread.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
        newItem.getPrice()
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
public void onStopButtonClicked() {
    cancelRefreshing();
}
```

The problem with regular timers is that they invoke the callback function on their own thread, not on the gui thread, so it requires the developer to ensure proper threading. Unfortunately the builtin java EventQueue does not support dispatching delayed tasks.

For this reason I like to have the following utility called `GuiTimer`, which will act as a pure gui-threaded timer:

```
public class GuiTimer {
    public static final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = 
            new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    public static interface Task {
        public void cancel();
    }

    private static class CancelStateTask implements Task {
        public volatile boolean canceled = false;

        @Override
        public void cancel() {
            this.canceled = true;
        }
    }

    public static Task schedule(final Runnable action) {
        CancelStateTask task = new CancelStateTask();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            if (!task.canceled)
                action.run();
        });
        return task;
    }

    public static Task schedule(final Runnable command, long delay,
            TimeUnit unit) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.schedule(
                () -> EventQueue.invokeLater(command), delay, unit);
        return () -> future.cancel(false);
    }

    public static Task scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,
            long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                () -> EventQueue.invokeLater(command), initialDelay,
                period, unit);
        return () -> future.cancel(false);
    }

    public static Task scheduleWithFixedDelay(Runnable command,
            long initialDelay, long delay, TimeUnit unit) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                () -> EventQueue.invokeLater(command), initialDelay, delay,
                unit);
        return () -> future.cancel(false);
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It would be nice to have some utility named e.g. GuiTimer"* - You mean, something like Swing Timer?

Comment: @MadProgrammer So it turns out I reinvented the wheel. It's s shame I didn't know about swing Timers, and sad that nobody corrected me until now. I'll update my answer, and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm in no way sure how this *should* be done, but I think I have a suggestion for how you could make it work. 
In a project I'm working on at the moment I use ExecutorService to handle my thread pool. I have to mention here, that I started working with threads in Java a little over a week ago myself, so I apologize if what I'm suggestion is too basic or wrong.

My suggestion is, that you could create a static boolean variable that you could use for controlling your loop. Code could look something like this:

```
public static boolean isRunning;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService executerService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    executerService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isRunning=true;
            while (isRunning){
                System.out.println("hello world"); //Your loop here
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Whenever you set the isRunning boolean to false the loop will stop, and the Thread will finish after a little while.

As for observer-observable classes I don't know this and I'm not sure I understand your last question.

Comment: thanks for your answer. With the observer pattern I would do something like you did. I'd create a new classe called Clock (that would extend/implement thread) and I'd have a function which would do this while you are doing. And then I'd add observers that after the sleep(5000) is done, they would be notified and execute a specific function, in my case the observers would be the items and the function to execute `getPrice()`. I don't know how I could execute the getPrice() function for every item with the solution you provided since I've never used ExecutorService

Comment: Thank you for replying to my answer :)
The Executors.newCachedThreadPool() is an implementation of ExecutorService that manages threads for you in a thread pool. So this implementation will spawn threads if none are available when you call the .execute() command. The execute command takes a Runnable as parameter, which could be an instance of the Task class if your GUI is made in JavaFX?
As for the "for every item" part, do you have all your items in an ArrayList? You could make an enhanced for loop:
`for(Item i : yourarraylist)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) to schedule a repeating task.

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially

Something along the lines of this code should do the trick.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    public void run() {
        getPrice(); //your task
    }
};

timer.schedule(task, 0, 5000); //first is delay, second is repeat period

...
// on button click, simple cancel the task
task.cancel()
```

Comment: where would I declare the Timer object, inside the ItemGUI or inside each item? Should I have one task for each item?

Comment: I would put the timer declaration in the GUI class cause you only need to create one (though garbage collection will do with many timers alright). But the tasks have to be created anew every time because once you cancel a task you cannot reschedule it.