# Slowing Down Program's execution to show steps

Tags: java, repaint

I have a program that runs a basic algorithm for solving a puzzle. I am trying to slow it down so that the user can see the algorithm in action. I want the program to show the steps that it takes to solve the puzzle. I have tried to use a timer and even thread.sleep to try and slow it down. However, my GUI (JPanel) is not repainting before or after the delay statement. What is happening is the delay is happening and the algorithm is solving step by step, but the program GUI is not updating/repainting to show the steps. Here is the code for that section:

```
delay(System.currentTimeMillis(), 500);
repaint();
```

The delay part is all good. Can anybody tell me why the JPanel is not repainting?

Here is the delay method that I made:

```
public static void delay (long a, int x)  //Simple Delay Method
{
    while((System.currentTimeMillis()-a) < (x/10)){}
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the piece of code that repaints the JPanel?

Comment: There is no delay function in standard java. What library do you use? Show us more code, what you describe could be good in principle. However it's hard to find flaws in code what we don't see

Comment: The originally included code is all that is being used for the repaint

Answer (score 1):

You can't just sleep the UI thread and wait for repaint to happen, that will stop all user and os interaction for that time (including repaint events). From the [repaint documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint()):

> If this component is a lightweight component, this method causes a call to this component's paint method as soon as possible.

*As soon as possible* does not mean *immediately*, it will most likely schedule a repaint, which will run when the ui thread is released.

You have to change your algorithm tohold it's state in an object, and make it possible to execute step-by-step, and [use a timer like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240070/call-function-every-x-time-without-blocking-the-gui-java/34240495#34240495).

---

Example:

```
public class SwingMain extends JFrame {
    public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public String state = "Initial";

        private JButton btn_start;

        public MyPanel() {
            super();
            btn_start = new JButton("Start");
            add(btn_start);
            btn_start.addActionListener(e -> doSolve());
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setFont(getFont());
            g.drawString(state, 10, 20);
        };

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(640, 480);
        }
    }

    private List<String> states;
    private int stateIndex;
    protected Task token;

    private MyPanel pnl_main;

    public SwingMain() {
        super("Step by step");
        setupUi();
    }

    protected void setupUi() {
        pnl_main = new MyPanel();
        getContentPane().add(pnl_main);
    }

    private List<String> modelSolve() {
        return Arrays.asList("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth");
    }

    public void doSolve() {
        this.stateIndex = 0;
        this.states = modelSolve();

        if (token != null)
            token.cancel();
        token = GuiTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            if (stateIndex >= states.size()) {
                token.cancel();
            } else {
                pnl_main.state = states.get(stateIndex);
                stateIndex++;
                pnl_main.repaint();
            }
        }, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            SwingMain frame = new SwingMain();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println(frame.pnl_main.getWidth());
            System.out.println(frame.pnl_main.getHeight());

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using thread.sleep but it didn't work so I am using a Timer that executes a step per ___ seconds. However, it doesn't repaint after waiting for  ___ amount of time.

Comment: @AntonioK Then show us more of your code, somewhere must be a flaw

Comment: The algorithm works through a recursive method. Every time the recursive method is called upon, the code I included is executed. The delay works (I have a system.out.println statement to ensure that it does. The repaint just isn't happening. Is there any reason that it shouldn't repaint?

Comment: @AntonioK Yes, there is a reason, as I said you are blocking the UI thread. You could for example save the steps of the solutionin a list, and display them one after another in a timer.