# Is there a way to make an ActionListener execute code as it reads it?

Tags: java, time, actionlistener

I've noticed that whenever an `ActionListener` method is called, it seems to accumulate the results, and then after the method is finished, it displays all the results at once. For example, in my program, I have several `wait(int milliseconds)` method calls. With this code, whenever I press a button, there is a long pause where it seems to be frozen, but then it displays everything at once. Is there a way to make it execute the code as it reads it?

Comment: What do you expect us to say without seeing any of your code? You need to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample) at least.

Comment: Take a look at SwingWorker or Swing Timer to see if they fulfil your requirements

Comment: @MadProgrammer I found SwingWorker on the docs, but I couldn't find Swing Timer... Could you give me a link for that? Thanks!

Comment: There are at least 3 `Timer` classes in the core library, the one you're looking for is [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) (aka Swing `Timer`). Also have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer That worked great! Thanks for your help! Now how do I mark this question as answered since your answer was a comment and not technically a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could use a `SwingWorker` or a Swing `Timer`

Have a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

A worker will allow you to run a long running or blocking process in the background (off the EDT), but provides methods to re-sync updates to the UI.  A timer will call the registered `ActionListener` within the context of the EDT, allowing you to safely update the UI from within in it after a specified delay (and possible repeatedly)

Answer (score 2):

Use swingworker class which uses method doInBackground for  Background process and at the same time you can call its publish method to work with process to display results with background processing see 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish-V...-

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `wait` in any listener on the Gui thread. Use instead timed callback, for example using my `GuiTimer` class here: [Call function every x time without blocking the GUI Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240070/call-function-every-x-time-without-blocking-the-gui-java/34240495#34240495)

Comment: To be honest, a SwingWorker would simpler and easier to use and achieve the same basic results. A Swing Timer might also do the same job

Comment: @MadProgrammer I feel like it's not a good idea to use `Thread.sleep` for any timing. Whether SwingWorkers create a new thread or take one from a thread pool, it will cause that thread to do nothing for a period of time, while holding resources (thread id's, memory for the stack, etc...) Or am I missing something?

Comment: It depends on the requirements of the OP. Personally, if they need to call a method at regular intervals, a Swing `Timer` will do, if they need to perform long running operations, a `SwingWorker` will be better. As to the use of `Thread.sleep`, the only rule I have is, don't do it in the context of the EDT.  The time it takes to start/spin up a thread probably isn't going to be noticeable to the user, a frozen UI is

Comment: You've also got to realise that almost any timer is going to rely on Thread.sleep, as no (Java) timer  guarantee an exact time, they only guarantee "at least" timing ;)

Comment: But these nice swing Timers you pointed out use a single thread to do all the timing as per the documentation, no matter how many Timers you instantiate, just like a single threaded ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, (which I like very much). Thats better than starting a new thread for every second to wait, isn't it. But right, these must use Thread.sleep internally (unless there is some fancy os specific low level timed callback employed here, which I doubt)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, it looks like it uses TimeUnit.sleep internally